# Ansible strip white space

Tags: ansible, jinja2

When I try to run some commands on nxos devices, the output has a white space at the end. I have to compare the output to an existing variable list. The whitespace at the end is causing the comparison to go false. How to make use of .strip() function in a list of strings?

```
- name: Current TACACS server host before
    nxos_command:
      commands:
        - sh run | include 'tacacs-server host'
register: runconfserafter

- debug:
    var: runconfserafter
```

The output of this comes up like this:

```
"stdout_lines": [
        [
            "tacacs-server host 1.1.1.1 key 7 \"HelloWorld\" ",
            "tacacs-server host 2.2.2.2 key 7 \"HelloWorld\""
        ],
     ]
```

When I compare this line with my desired variables, I can't get it matched because of the white space on the first line at the end.

Comment: Please indent your code properly when posting questions.

Answer (score 25):

To apply a function to list elements use [`map` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map). To strip whitespace use [`trim` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#trim).

```
"{{ runconfserafter.stdout_lines | map('trim') | list }}"
```

Comment: links referenced in the answer are ghosted

Comment: Ansible [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html) refer us to the Jinja2 documentation for info about some filters. Here are [map](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) and [trim](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.trim) and [others](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters)