# Unable to format string passed as multiline jenkins parameter to Ansible

Tags: jenkins, split, ansible, formatting, newline

I have a multi-line string Jenkins parameter.

There is no trim feature provided by jenkins for multiline string as we have for single line string parameter.

Thus the user may enter details having leading, trailing whitespaces or simply blank lines in the multiline parameter like below.

```
/tmp/file1.txt 


    /tmp/file2.txt

/tmp/file3.txt
```

I pass the above Jenkins multiline parameter to ansible playbook using Jenkin's ansible plugin.

I used ansible to convert the list of files provided in the multiline parameter as   a comma seperated string.

Expected output: `/tmp/file1.txt,/tmp/file2.txt,/tmp/file3.txt`

Ansible debug shows the parameter being passed looks like this:

```
[0;34mextra_vars: (u"files='\n/tmp/file1.txt \n\n\n    /tmp/file2.txt\n\n
/tmp/file3.txt\n'",
```

Here is my playbook:

```
   - name: Format file list to be comma seperated
     set_fact:
       files_list: "{{ files  | replace('\n',',')}}"

Ouput:
,/tmp/file1.txt ,,,    /tmp/file2.txt,,/tmp/file3.txt,
```

I tried converting the jenkins variable inside a Jenkins execute shell script before passing it to ansible but that did not help as well.

Below is one such attempt on unix shell script:

```
files=`echo $files | cat -s | sed '1d;$d';`
```

Can you please suggest ?

Comment: You can use `trim`. See reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015315/ansible-strip-white-space).

Comment: Off hand, you could convert the multi-line string parameter into an array, remove all of the empty elements, and then convert it back into a string with a `,` delimiter. This would be slightly messy though, and it only handles the whitespace and newline issues. If the users put other bad characters into the input, then those would need to be handled too.

Comment: Trim helped resolve the issue. Thank you @moonmoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put this here so the answer is clear then.

The solution to the issue is to use [trim](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#trim). It will get rid of leading and trailing spaces.